# How to prevent visits to Hangouts on school-issued Chromebook?

Tags: google-hangouts

My twelve-year-old has OCD.  His school recently issued a Chromebook to each student in secondary school.  My son compulsively goes to Hangouts and his grades are suffering.  I am working on getting the school to block Hangouts, but I have not been successful yet.  While I'm working on that, I'd like to set up some sort of redirect, with perhaps a script, so that when he tries to visit Hangouts on the Chromebook while he's at school, the browser will automatically go to a different address (such as Google Classroom).

How can I do this?

(There's no point in trying to guide me through killing his google+ account.  I've tried that.  It refuses to die.)

Comment: Just at home or always/everywhere? Easy path at home would be something like [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/URL-Redirect-Prank-using-dd-wrt/). I'd also consider whether school-wide blocking is the right answer to your child's specific problem. There are lots of kids who might use hangouts appropriately and w/o issue. I'd suggest they create an additional org group in GAFE w different app activations.

Comment: @TomWoodward - I didn't see any productive use.

Comment: *Just at home or always/everywhere?*  At school!

Comment: I don't think you'll have much success outside the org group. On the other end of things, not knowing the size of your school system, I'd still suggest that it'd be hard to for you to see much beyond 5 or 10 kids (or maybe just your one). There are lots of people doing interesting things with hangouts in the k12 space.

Comment: @TomWoodward - I don't understand "org group".  //  I suppose those hangouts have an adult participant.  At any rate, I'm not asking for assistance with convincing my district to block hangouts -- I just want to jerryrig my student's district-issued Chromebook in such a way that if he tries to go to hangouts, it will redirect to another page.

Comment: The organization groups would need to be done by the school. Essentially, they can create groups of users that have (or don't have) access to particular Google products. [This](http://superuser.com/questions/595267/hosts-file-for-chromebook) gets into what you might be able to do on the machine but I'd be really surprised if they've left the machines this open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The school district uses GoGuardian for their filtering.  They refused to set up a special set of rules for a subset of students.  I ended up putting a second layer of filtering on top of the district's filtering, with Qustodio.  It wasn't easy, and it wasn't a perfect solution (the current system is over-filtering slightly), but the child is now able to get his schoolwork done.

*For anyone looking to do something like this for their child: It can't be done without minimal cooperation from the school's IT people.  (It took me from September to May, and a civil rights complaint, to achieve this.)*